# Powershell select-string not working as planned for an pattern array

Tags: arrays, powershell, select-string

I am trying to search a log file for certain times which are stored in an array. I am then passing the matches back to a variable for further processing, but I am stumbling at the first hurdle.
 I am trying to pattern match with the following:

```
$times = "19/11/2014 23:56","19/11/2014 23:57","19/11/2014 23:58","19/11/2014 23:59"
Get-Content D:\tmp\App.log |  select-string -Pattern $times
```

The App.log file looks like this:

19/11/14 23:59:11.470  [2752] INFO  AppAdmin - Logon Request user1@google.com
19/11/14 23:59:11.470  [2752] INFO  AppAdmin - Logon Request for user = rsa@metib.ru succeeded.
19/11/14 23:59:12.687  [2752] INFO  AppAdmin - onStreamOpened called: item = user1@google.com
19/11/14 23:59:12.687  [2752] INFO  AppAdmin - PrivateStreamEvents::onStreamOpened - message type 0: item = user1@google.com
19/11/14 23:59:12.765  [2752] INFO  AppAdmin - Logon Request user1@google.com

So really the above lines should be passed to the console.

Any advice as to what could be going wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
19/11/14 23:59
```

Is not match to

```
19/11/2014 23:59
```